# Experimental Design with two treatment levels, random effects, and technical constraints

Tags: r, experiment-design, split-plot, latin-square

I'm trying to plan an experiment and the experimental design is giving me headaches because it's too complex to wrap my only-statistics-101-capable head around. Basically I want to subject plants of different genotypes to drought stress or not (treatment) but also pay attention to positional random factors (position of the plant in the greenhouse). I have a total of 384 spaces in the greenhouse organized in 12 lanes (longitudinal position) and 8 columns (latitudinal position). Each of the spaces will be occupied by 1 tray that holds 6 plants, and treatment (watering) can only be applied to the whole tray of 6 plants. I have 48 genotypes, so there'll be 24 replicates per genotype and treatment.

It appears to me that a split-plot design would be most appropriate, because I have two "treatment" levels (watering and genotype), and watering can only be applied to a tray of 6 plants whereas genotype can be "applied" to each plant individually. Since I have two random factors, a Latin Squares design within the split-plot design seemed sensible to me.

Of course I don't want to do this by hand, so I installed the `agricolae` package in R that can create such layouts for me:

```r
library(agricolae)
treatments = c("Drought", "Well Watered")
genotypes  = seq(1, 48)
design.split(treatments, genotype, r=24, design="lsd")
```

And indeed, that does create an experimental layout, just unfortunately it doesn't know/care about my constraints:

- it wants to put each genotype in every tray, but I only have space for 6 plants per tray
- Latin **Square** design of course assumes my longitudinal and latitudinal effects have an equal number of levels, but I have 12 lanes and 8 columns
- (on a more technical level) it seems to ignore my r option and is only giving me one replicate per treatment, genotype and position.

Now, my question is: What would be a good experimental design for this situation and does anyone know of a software package (R, python, Julia, whatever) that can generate an experimental plan?